# Echo with auto \n from data base

Tags: php, mysql

Hey I have on my database a text with 800 chracters when I echo it out it display in just one line getting too big and bad for read,

```
echo mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `message` FROM `pm` WHERE `pm_id` = '1'"));
```

How do I put 
 or \n automatic on the end of every line because there is differents datas inserted in the database and do manualy for every one is hard.

**edit:**
I want to meke it like: one \n after 100 characters or something like that.

Comment: `echo nl2br($data)` , `// $data = data from DB`

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty that would work If I had \n's on the text but I dont is just normal characters, I want to get the normal characters and put <br> or \n like after 100 characters, you understand?

Comment: Argh... why so many `mysql_*` questions today? Peple: if a crummy extension is finally deprecated: stop using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `wordwrap` function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php

```
echo wordwrap($data, 100, "\n"); // Or use "<br/>" in html
```

There also is a 4. parameter. If you data does not contain any spaces, wordwrap can not break between words. If you set the 4. parameter to `true`, wordwrap will cut no matter if within a word or not.

```
// cut after 100, no matter if inside a word.
echo wordwrap($data, 100, "\n", true);
```

Comment: why? What's the message?

Comment: Im working on a pm system for the website and the message the an user sends to another can get really big, and for show it for the user that recived the message is only showing in one line even with wordrap();

Comment: Sorry, if you use other specific ways to output text, we need to have much more information to help you. Is it HTML you are showing or plain text? Did you try "<br/>" as seperator in above code? Is your other system manipulating your text too?

Comment: I have `$message =  mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT message FROM pm WHERE pm_id = '$id'"));` and than: `$newText = wordwrap($message['message'] , 100, "<br/>");`

Comment: see edited note. Other than that, we need to know what happens with `$newText` between the wordwrap function the it's arrival at the users browser.

Comment: like in your edit says, its because the message dont have blank spaces

Answer (score 0):

put it in a div, and set div width. That will solve your problem. Like this:

```
#CSS

.sample{
    width:50px;
}
```

and here's some sample html

```
<div class="sample">
   #your results from database here
</div>
```

Comment: There's nothing in this question to suggest that OP wants to present the data in a particular way. This is probably a one-off script to update a table. CSS won't cut it here